# URL problems in codeigniter: I have to manually type URL to check errors/results

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

I don't get Codeigniter URL's. my current base_url is `http://localhost/codeigniter/`

I wanted to retrieve data from my database, but it always tells me that

> Message: Undefined variable: query

or

> Message: Trying to get property of non-object

I am sure that my Controllers, Model and Views are working fine. My database is not empty but everytime I type in this url `http://localhost/codeigniter/index.php/c_test/` it won't show the results/errros, I have to always specify the URL to see if I got errors `http://localhost/codeigniter/index.php/c_test/getgrades`(notice I have to add getGrades so that I can see the results)

I also tried to var_dump it and yes it is not NULL. Another problem is, it tells me `Message: Undefined variable: query` what is the reason for that?

(I will show you the code, so that you would get what I mean)
Controller:

```
function getGrades() {
       $data['query'] = $this->m_test->result_getGrades(); 
       $this->load->view('v_display', $data);
    }
```

Model:

```
function result_getGrades()
    {
          $this->db->select('grades.blockcode,subjectblocking.subjectcode,subjects.description,grades.final');
          $this->db->from('grades');
          $this->db->join('subjectblocking','grades.blockcode=subjectblocking.blockcode');
          $this->db->join('subjects','subjectblocking.subjectcode=subject.subjectcode');
          $query->$this->db->get();
          return $query->result();
    }
```

Views:

```
 <?php foreach ($query as $row): ?>

               <?php echo $row->studentid;?><br>
               <?php echo $row->subjectcode;?><br>
               <?php echo $row->description;?><br>
               <?php echo $row->final;?><br>


         <?php endforeach; ?>
```

How come query is undefined? Do I have to check/change something on my `config.php` and `autoload.php`?

Comment: did you get array in $this->m_test->result_getGrades(); from this code....?

Comment: problem is likely to be here: `$query->$this->db->get();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try by replacing one line of $query->$this->db->get(); to $query = $this->db->get(); in your model function,

```
function result_getGrades()
    {
          $this->db->select('grades.blockcode,subjectblocking.subjectcode,subjects.description,grades.final');
          $this->db->from('grades');
          $this->db->join('subjectblocking','grades.blockcode=subjectblocking.blockcode');
          $this->db->join('subjects','subjectblocking.subjectcode=subject.subjectcode');
          $query = $this->db->get();
          return $query->result();
    }
```

Comment: wow thanks for that! It lessen the error however i still got one more `Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on a non-object in D:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter\application\models\m_test.php on line 19`

Comment: In result_getGrades function write like that at last,if($query){ return $query->result();}

Comment: Also before return first print your query by, echo $this->db->last_query();die(); execute that query directly through phpmyadmin